# Excel Notifications via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Good Afternoon All,

I have a question, I want to write VBA codes that will verify and notify me for the past due dates for me and highlight the cell/s in Red. I have done some codes below. but the problem is it also highlight the empty cell see attached image. For the cells that doesn't date it should be remain with a white background.

3 in the codes is the number of days.

[image: screeshot of sample data]

```
Sub SubbasecreateNotifications()


Dim i As Long
'lastrow As Long
'lastrow = Worksheets("Subbase").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
i = 9
'To lastrow

For Each cell In Range("G9:G400")

If cell.Value + 3 <> Date And Cells(i, 7) = "" Then
Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3


Else
Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 2

End If
i = i + 1
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for a valid date  with [isDate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SubbasecreateNotifications()

    Const OVERDUE = 3 'days
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, count As Long
    Dim iColor As Integer
    
    With Worksheets("Subbase")
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 9 To lastrow
            iColor = 2 ' white
            If IsDate(.Cells(i, "B")) And Cells(i, "G") = "" Then
               If DateDiff("d", Cells(i, "B"), Date) > OVERDUE Then
                   iColor = 3 ' red
                   count = count + 1
               End If
            End If
            .Cells(i, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = iColor
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox count & " overdue"

End Sub
```

Comment: Column B has the date, not G (regarding `If DateDiff("d", Cells(i, "G"), Date) > OVERDUE Then`)

Comment: @CDP1802 thank you for your time to go through my question. one more question, is there any possibility that i can for  "Const OVERDUE = 3 'days" to reference it to a range on a different sheet. '' Const OVERDUE = 3 'days''

Comment: @Eikky Yes, but declare it as a variable `Dim OVERDUE as Integer`. Then `OVERDUE = Worksheets("AnotherSheet").Range("A1").Value2`

Comment: @CDP1802 thank you very much for effort. I will be back with more questions soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
If cell.Value + 3 <> Date And Cells(i, 7) = "" Then
```

Can be broken down to the following psuedo code:

```
If the cell value + 3 is not Todays date AND column G of the current row is ""
```

If the date cell is blank, `If cell.Value + 3 <> Date` evaluates to True, if column G's cell is also `""` then both conditions are `True` and the cell is filled red.

Try adding an additional criteria before this line.

Something like;

```
    Dim TargetCell As Range
    
    For Each TargetCell In Range("G9:G400")
        If TargetCell.Offset(0, -5).Value > 0 Then
            If TargetCell.Offset(0, -5).Value + 3 <> Date And TargetCell.Value = "" Then
                TargetCell.Offset(0, -5).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Else
                TargetCell.Offset(0, -5).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            End If
        End If
    Next TargetCell
```

Sample test output (based on `Date` evaluating to June 2, 2021):

[image: snip of sample data targeted at columns B and G]

Rather than referencing your `Cell` variable and `Cells` Objects, I've kept the code using the (now declared) `TargetCell` Range variable. As we are looping over cells in column G, to target `Column B` where the date value is, I use the `Range.Offset` property to target `-5` columns from the `TargetCell`.

This method also eliminates the need to have a *counter* variable (`i` in your code) that increments with each iteration making the code simpler to read and follow.

Comment: `TargetCell.Value + 3 <> Date` ??

Comment: @Samuel Everson, Thank you for your response, maybe my post was not clear. what i am trying to is Column B, after three days counting from the date on Column B. if Column G is empty then column B should be highlited.

Comment: @CDP1802 should be `Offset(0, -5)` well spotted.